# What is the -I equivalent for g++/gcc compiling that still searches local file directories?

Tags: gcc, g++

I've switched compilers from a GreenHills (6.0+) one to ARM (8.3) gcc/g++ compiler and see that -I option for includes is deprecated. When I try to use the -iquote or -isystem I run into a problem where when it searches for includes it doesn't search the local directory first. This issue goes away with -I (but I'd like to not use deprecated flags). What is the correct flag for includes where the local directory is searched first?

Similar to [GCC header search path deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832390/gcc-header-search-path-deprecated)

Comment: What makes you think `-I` is deprecated?  The `-I-` option is deprecated, but that is a special case, basically unrelated to "normal" `-I`

Comment: @ChrisDodd When I use -I the note: obsolete option -I- used, please use -iquote instead. So I guess I am referring to -I- Thanks.

Comment: The main effect of `-I-` is to not search in the current directory for `#include "`...`"` directives.  There's no way to do that with `-iquote`, but at least those directories specified by `-iquote` will be searched before it.  For "includes where the local directory is searched first", use `-I` (with no `-I-`)